# Switch to turn off motor and another to turn the motor on

Tags: motor, switches

I have a DC motor that turns a gear which then has an arm that will hit a switch which turns the motor off.

Is there a way for me to build this without using a microcontroller?

Like I start the motor with switch1 then the motor hits switch2 which then turns the motor off, so to activate it again I need to press switch1.

Comment: Activate it again so it does what? It is just going to immediately run into switch 2 again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possibly simpler method is as follows:

- Set the motor up with a wheel which engages a microswitch (or similar)

[image]

Wire the microswitch as SW1, the starting switch as SW2:

[image]

With SW2 unpressed, the motor will go until the tab engages the microswitch, breaking the normally-closed side.  It stays there until you press the start switch SW2 for long enough to move the wheel off the microswitch.

I once made a doorbell like this, out of a CD-ROM motor and a music-box mechanism.  It was arranged to play the whole of the Pink Panther tune.  All was fine until the tab broke and it played for about an hour: everybody was hoping their patience lasted longer than the battery.

The tab was glued onto the wheel, marked 2 in Wikipedia image:

[image]

Comment: This is more like what I was thinking about this makes it more clear for me what I also actually am looking for thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can relatively easily do this: the first **momentary switch** turns on a **relay**, which is normally off, and is parallel to that switch. So, turning on the current through the relay's coil makes the relay stay on (we call that a "latch"):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXXlaC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To turn the motor off, you need to turn the current through the relay. Easy, use a momentary switch that's normally closed to interrupt your current:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTRNBR.png)</sup>

Comment: Thank you I will look into this aswell.

Comment: You're welcome! On this site, it's encouraged to reward good answers with an upvote, so no need to thank me in a comment :)